# Large blank above table

Tags: tables

I am having problems with a too large blank space above my (not even large) table.

My expectation was to have the table sit right beneath the sectionname and not this far down, with nothing in between.

So I am wondering what is causing this and honestly have no clue. Any hints/advice would be appreciated.

I am using MikTeX and TeXMaker and compiling with PDFLaTeX, btw.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

[...]


\section*{Aufgabe 1.4}


\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|l}
$\delta$ & 0           & 1           & B               &                            \\ \hline
$q_0$    & $(q_0,0,R)$ & $(q_0,1,R)$ & $(q_1,B,L)$     &    \\
$q_1$    & $(q_2,0,L)$ & $(q_2,1,L)$ & $(\bar{q},B,N)$ &    \\
$q_2$    & $(q_3,1,L)$ & $(q_3,0,L)$ & $(\bar{q},1,N)$ &    \\
$q_3$    & $(q_3,0,L)$ & $(q_3,1,L)$ & $(\bar{q},B,R)$ & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: Way too larg blank space between the section and the table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you can use `\vspace{}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is LaTeXs peference for putting floats (like `figure` or `table`) at the top or, in this case, at the bottom of pages. If you don't like this, you can solve it with the `H` option for floats, forcing LaTeX to put the floats exactly where you have them in the source.

Add

```
\usepackage{float}
```

to the preamble and use the `table` placement option `[H]` (instead of your currently used `[]` to have your table placed directly below your section heading.

Comment: @Bernard both of your solutions work fine. I mark carsten's as solution, because it's a bit more detailed and explanatory. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `float` and its `[H]` placement option, which may result in unwanted white spaces, you can try simply adding the placement option `[!htb]`. For this code, it works fine.